Problema de resolución de DNS en Free Hotspot a través del router móvil: "No hay dirección asociada al nombre de host"
Estoy utilizando una máquina Ubuntu conectada a través de un router GL.iNet para acceder a un punto de acceso gratuito, pero me encuentro con problemas de resolución de DNS. Cuando intento acceder a la página de inicio de sesión del punto de acceso, obtengo el siguiente error:

Error resolving “wifi.sncf”: No address associated with hostname

Aquí están los detalles de la red:
IP address: XX.XX.X.XXX
Netmask: 255.255.248.0
Gateway: 10.20.0.2
DNS Server: 10.20.0.2

Pasos que he dado:

Verificado y configurado manualmente los DNS a los de Google (8.8.8.8 y 8.8.4.4) en la máquina Ubuntu. Desconozco si hay que hacerlo en la interfaz GL.iNet y cómo.
He reiniciado el Network Manager en la máquina Ubuntu.

Sin embargo, sigo recibiendo el mismo error. Al probar la resolución DNS con nslookup y dig, los resultados son los siguientes:
(base) ubuntu@ubuntu-GE66-Raider-11UH:~/Desktop$ nslookup wifi.sncf
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find wifi.sncf: No answer

(base) ubuntu@ubuntu-GE66-Raider-11UH:~/Desktop$ dig wifi.sncf

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> wifi.sncf
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58279
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;wifi.sncf.         IN  A

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 11 15:09:22 CEST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 38

¿Qué puede estar causando este problema y cómo puedo resolverlo? ¿Hay algo que me falte en la configuración de DNS o algún otro paso que deba dar para solucionar el problema, teniendo en cuenta que utilizo el router GL.iNet?

¿Cuál es tu modelo de GL.iNet? ¿Has conectado a la página de administración de tu router?  Creo que es necesario que accedas al router para conectarte al punto de acceso wifi.

Gracias por tu comentario @PeterM Mi modelo es Mini Smart Router. Voy a la página de administración del enrutador pero no puedo conectarme a la página de registro del punto de acceso
